# JSLint : Notepadd++ : how to see console.log()

Tags: logging, printing, console, notepad++, jslint

My .js-file is only `console.log("abc");`. I enabled already development mode in the JSLint options. How can I get JSLint to show me the log like `System.out.println()` in Java does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSLint doesn't actually execute your code, it just tells you if there are any errors with it.

If you want to execute it, load it up inside of a webpage with a `<script src="..." type="text/javascript">` tag (where the `...` is the name of your `.js` file)